# New to jQuery/Ajax how can I add a user relation to creating a new review?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, jquery

I have been trying to get to grips with jQuery and been following a [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery) on adding an Ajax add review form, which works fine but I would now like to add into it the ability for a review to belong to a user as well as a venue.

**Reviews controller**

```
def create
    @review = Review.create!(params[:review])
    @review.venue = @venue
    if @review.save
      flash[:notice] = 'Thank you for reviewing this venue!'
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to venue_path(@venue) }
        format.js
      end
    else
      render :action => :new
    end
  end
```

**views\reviews\create.js.erb**

```
$("#new_review").before('<div id="flash_notice"><%= escape_javascript(flash.delete(:notice)) %></div>');
$("#reviews_count").html("<%= pluralize(@review.venue.reviews.count, 'Review') %>");
$("#reviews").append("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => @review)) %>");
$("#new_review")[0].reset();
```

I have tried changing the controller to:

```
  def create
    @review = @current_user.reviews.create!(params[:review])
    @review.venue = @venue
    if @review.save
      flash[:notice] = 'Thank you for reviewing this venue!'
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to venue_path(@venue) }
        format.js
      end
    else
      render :action => :new
    end
  end
```

but it just wont submit, with no errors.

I think I have the models set correctly with belongs_to and has_many, I think this is a controller issue I'll add other code bits if needed.

**Development log**

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `reviews' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/reviews_controller.rb:14:in `create'
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Firstly, where is @venue set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that your error is residing with `@current_user`. According to your development log, `@current_user` is `nil` when you call `@current_user.reviews` on it. I would say track down where this `@current_user` instance variable is being set and find out why it is `nil`. Now, what kind of authentication are you using? Most authentication plugins, especially those used by Ryan Bates of the Railscasts you mentioned, use a local variable, say just `current_user`, as the means to access the currently signed in user. I know I do in all my code.

So, rewrite the line as

```
@review = current_user.reviews.create!(params[:review])
```

and see if that works. If it doesn't, change it back and then track down where this `@current_user` is being set. Chances are good it is being set in a `before_filter :method_name` at the beginning of your controller.

Comment: thanks for the answer I'll check it out when I finish work, my authentication is from another railscast, can't remember which but it's without any plugins.

Comment: I've tried it and it works, thanks very much, fantastic answer!

Answer (score 0):

Calling create! (with exclamation mark) will throw an exception and thus abort your create action if saving fails. Check your log/development.log for these exceptions.

Use build instead of create and lose the exclamation mark.

```
def create
  @review = @current_user.reviews.build(params[:review])
  @review.venue = @venue
  if @review.save
    flash[:notice] = 'Thank you for reviewing this venue!'
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to venue_path(@venue) }
      format.js
    end
  else
    render :action => :new
  end
end
```

Comment: It doesn't change the outcome, I've added the development log output to my question.

Comment: Oddly enough, Ryan Bates uses "create!" in his Railscast. http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery